# is this proper openMP usage? (or: can I trust the default settings?)

Tags: c++, openmp, member

I am presently using openMP for the first time, and have hit my head against the "data members cannot be private"-rule.

I would like to know whether the below is valid, or if it will eventually break:

```
class network
{
    double tau;
    void SomeFunction();
};

void network::SomeFunction()
{
    #pragma omp parallel for // <-the openMP call
    for (uint iNeu=0;iNeu<nNeurons;++iNeu)
    {
        neurons[iNeu].timeSinceSpike+=tau;  //tau is defined in some other place
        neurons[iNeu].E+=tau*tau;
    }   
}
```

So, I am using the minimal syntax, and letting openMP figure out everything on its own. This version compiles, and the output is correct (so far).
What I tried before that was

```
void network::SomeFunction()
{
    #pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(neurons) firstprivate(tau)  // <-the openMP call
    for (uint iNeu=0;iNeu<nNeurons;++iNeu)
    {
        neurons[iNeu].timeSinceSpike+=tau; //tau is defined in some other place
        neurons[iNeu].E+=tau*tau;
    }   
}
```

However, as hinted, that won't compile, presumably because tau and neurons are data members of network.

The question then is, if I have really just been lucky in my runs of the first version, and whether I have to do something like

```
void network::SomeFunction()
{
    double tempTau=tau;
    vector <neuron> tempNeurons=neurons; //in realtity this copy-process would be quite involved
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(tempNeurons) firstprivate(tempTau)// <-the openMP call
    for (uint iNeu=0;iNeu<nNeurons;++iNeu)
    {
        tempNeurons[iNeu].timeSinceSpike+=tempTau;
        tempNeurons[iNeu].E+=tempTau*tempTau;
    }   
}
```

Naturally, I would much prefer to stick with the present version, as it is so short and easy to read, but I would also like to trust my output :)
I am using gcc 4.6.1

Hope someone can educate me on the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, what you are initially doing should be fine:

- The reason is that you aren't modifying the `tau` member at all. So there's no reason to make it private in the first place. It's safe to asynchronously share the same value if it isn't modified.
- As for `neurons`, you are modifying the elements independently. So there's no problem here either.

When you declare a variable as `firstprivate`, it gets copy constructed into all the threads. So `shared(tempNeurons)` is definitely *not* what you want to do.

Comment: reading about the "atomic" clause, I get the impression that it would be better to write "#pragma omp atomic read" in front of each line using "tau"? is that correct? if so, then I'm not sure I understand when parallel reading can cause problems, and when I'm safe.

Comment: `atomic` is only needed when you have multiple writes from different threads. In this case, you're reading, but not writing. So `atomic` should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf

> Section 2.9.1, Data-sharing Attribute Rules
>
> - Variables appearing in threadprivate directives are threadprivate.
> - Variables with automatic storage duration that are declared in a scope inside the construct are private.
> - Objects with dynamic storage duration are shared.
> - Static data members are shared.
> - The loop iteration variable(s) in the associated for-loop(s) of a for or parallel for construct is (are) private.
> - Variables with const-qualified type having no mutable member are shared.
> - Variables with static storage duration that are declared in a scope inside the construct are shared.

```
...
```

> - The loop iteration variable(s) in the associated for-loop(s) of a for or parallel for construct may be listed in a private or lastprivate clause.
> - Variables with const-qualified type having no mutable member may be listed in a firstprivate clause.

However, I yet miss the default sharing attribute for automatic variables outside a construct.

Comment: what you are looking for stands in section 2.9.1.2 "Data-sharing Attribute Rules for Variables Referenced in a Region but not in a Construct"

Comment: @Callahan: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately I am bit out of the topic; if you want, feel free to edit my answer.